# New to Bash Scripting, having a strange issue with string comparison in if statement

Tags: bash

Ok, So I'm pretty new to Bash scripting, but I do have some decent experience in other languages.

My script is run from a Linux computer with an Android phone connected with USB debugging enabled.

The way my script works is you run it with `./myscript.sh APP_NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION`. So, for example, I am running `./myscript.sh SystemUI`, and it gets a list of all apps, and then it checks to see if `$1.apk` is in that list.

Here is how I am getting a list of system apps from my Android phone:

```
# Get list of files in system app directory
app_list=($(adb shell ls $app_path))
```

This is working fine, if I do this:

```
for file in ${app_list[@]}; do
    echo $file
done
```

Then it prints out all file names as expected.

Now I have this:

```
found=false
for file in ${app_list[@]}; do
        # This is ALWAYS resulting in false, even if the strings in fact match
        if [ "$1.apk" == "$file" ] || [ "$1.jar" == "$file" ]; then
        echo "TEST"
        found=true
        break
    fi
done
```

I'm sure I'm making some kind of syntax error, but I just can't figure it out, this is driving me nuts. I've looked over all kinds of examples on the net, and I can't find anything wrong with my code.

Comment: Try using single `=` instead of double `==` in the `test` (`[`) command.

Comment: Do to being new I can't answer my own question, but I did figure it out, just needed to sanitize the input, after 8 hours I'll answer my question with a little more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out almost right after I posted my question, but do to being new had to wait 8 hours before I could answer my own question. Anyways, here's the solution.

After I posted the question, suddenly a thought came to me, "what if the ls command were adding non-printable characters to the file names?", so I decided to sanitize the input, resulting in this:

```
for file in ${app_list[@]}; do
    file=${file//[^a-zA-Z0-9_. ]/} # This strips any non-printable characters
    # Thanks to naab for pointing out the regex conditional :)
    if [[ $file =~ "$1."("apk"|"jar") ]]; then
        found=true
        break
       fi
done
```

And now it works! B)

Answer (score 0):

You could test both cases in one condition :

```
if [[ $file =~  "${1}"\.(apk|jar) ]]; then
    echo "TEST"
    found=true
    break
fi
```

Comment: == is an alias for = according to the Bash documentation, when being used in conditionals

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 2 conditionals in one statement thing though, I did not know about that